# how to implement request GET in Python

Tags: python, api, get

I am having difficulties with the implementation of the query GET.
For example, I took no difficult task to bring in a convenient form the information on this page GET https://www.bitstamp.net/api/transactions/

Used API https://www.bitstamp.net/api/

I'm interested in everything from syntax to the modules you want to install for this request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to install an extra library, you can use pythons `urllib2` library that is just as easy for something like connecting to a url.

```
import urllib2
print urllib2.urlopen("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/transactions/").read()
```

For parsing that, use [pythons json library.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Answer (score 1):

Did you already seen this?
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

e.g:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
print response.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python lib for that, the [bitstamp-python-client](https://github.com/kmadac/bitstamp-python-client). Do not waste your time reinventing the wheel. ;-)